# Python, Selenium - Scroll Google Maps

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Bom dia.

Estou desenvolvendo um Script python onde ele acessa o Google Maps e pesquisa determinada loja e coleta os dados dela através do XPATH //*[@id="pane"].
Porém o Google Maps carrega a lista de lojas dinamicamente (eu acho), então ele pega no máximo até o 7 //*[@id="pane"], após isto ele não consegue visualizar os demais.

Através de pesquisa localizei algumas soluções como por ex.:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe', options=self.browserProfile)
brownser.get('your url here')
browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

ou

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com/maps/place/Bengaluru,+Karnataka/@12.95396,77.4908522,11z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x3bae1670c9b44e6d:0xf8dfc3e8517e4fe0!8m2!3d12.9715987!4d77.5945627")
option = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='hNLpDc-HiaYvf-DWDkFd-HiaYvf-haAclf']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",option)
```

Porém mesmo alterando ele não funciona, ele pula para a condição final e nem mesmo apresenta erro.

Saberiam me informar se existe algum modo de selecionar a lista do google maps e fazer scroll dela até o final ?

Obrigado.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -2):

Segue uma função para rolar página até o final:

```
def scroll_page(self):
    SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 0.5
    last_height = self.webdriver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    while True:
        # Scroll down to bottom
        self.webdriver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        # Wait to load page
        time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)
        # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
        new_height = self.webdriver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
        if new_height == last_height:
            break
        last_height = new_height
```